# Vector projection onto axis in PCA sequential algorithm

Tags: vectors, projection

I'm having trouble understanding why the $x'$ vector, that is the projection of the $x$ vector on the $w_1$ axis, is equivalent to $x'=w_1( w^T_1 x )$. Shouldn't $x'$ be equivalent to the dot product of the versor of the $w_1$ and the $x$ vector multiplied by the versor of the $w_1$ axis?

[image]

Comment: It may be the case that $\mathbf{w}_1$ is defined to be a unit vector in the algorithm as an initial condition, which I believe will answer your concern.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @ad2004 thanks, I think that's the only possible case